# Deny certain kinds of urls

Tags: php

I have a short url website where i only allow the creation of short urls from one website. I am trying to deny spammers from using the site to get spam urls into the database. They manage to get urls into the database that has either has something before the full url or  after the full url

**The urls in the database looks like this:**

```
https://myydomain.com/user/ni1zsuwjg2g8no4e2awkmm99a?utm_source=copy-link
```

***Example from the database where someone had managed to get "@" into the redirect url in form of "@ryui" before the actual url.***:

```
@ryui：https://myydomain.com/page/2r8jmcWVy7N0wM8eoX4CPJ?utm_source=copy-link
```

how can i deny this from being done with the code bellow ? i have the following function bellow but they still manage to get stuff into the the database with @ or text before the actual url begins.

```
function denyNonSite($url)
{
    $strAllow = 'myydomain.com'; 
    $strBase  = getBaseUrl($url);
    if(strpos($url, $strAllow) === false)
    {
        return true;
    }
            
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be doing this correctly. What's the issue you're facing? Can you show how you call the functions?

Comment: beware when using this code someone can easily fool your site into making any short links by creating a URL like e.g. `my.domain.com.evil.com`. Make sure the URL host **ends in** `my.domain.com`

Comment: Please see the updated question as someone had managed to get "@" into the redirect url in form of "@ryui" before the actual url.

Comment: Also note that `if (conditional) return true else return false` is identical to `return (conditional)`. No need for five lines of code where one will do. Also, if someone managed to do what shouldn't be possible: create a [mcve] test case that shows this off so that you can debug it. And then once you get stuck debugging, now your have all the code others need to help, which you can put in your post. So: please update your post with an MCVE that shows your code accepting that input (it doesn't need to store anything, just show given some input with `@`, and your code calls the result is bad.

Comment: (and note that your current code is just three unrelated functions - we can't tell whether you even call them at all, so that would be the first guess if things aren't working. But: SO posts should not require folks to guess, [all the details should already be in your post](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Hi again.
I updated my question a bit to se if you can help me now to tweak the function to deny any text before the url and after it like the one in the example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `strpos`, try parsing the URL and comparing the hostname. Fortunately, PHP has a built-in function, [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) that can help:

```php
function denyNonSite($url)
{
   return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) != 'mydomain.com';
}
```

According to the documentation, a malformed URL will return a boolean `false`, so this function will also correctly reject invalid URLs.